I want to figure out how to fix the errors I'm running into while scraping employee reviews from Indeed and Glassdoor using Scrapfly
nice to meet you!
I'm trying to use Scrapfly to scrape employee reviews from websites like Indeed or Glassdoor.
However, I'm facing a persistent issue that I just can't seem to solve.
The data I'm trying to scrape isn't coming through—only the titles show up in the results.
No matter what I try, I keep running into the dreaded 'empty dataframe' problem.
I've followed other people's code examples, but it just doesn't work for me.
How are others successfully scraping these reviews?
Is there anyone out there who can lend a helping hand?
I'd really appreciate your kindness!
!pip install beautifulsoup4 pandas lxml requests

!git clone https://github.com/scrapfly/python-sdk.git
%cd python-sdk
!pip install .

from scrapfly.client import ScrapflyClient

import os
os.environ["SCRAPFLY_KEY"] = "my key"

import os
import pandas as pd
from scrapfly.client import ScrapflyClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Scrapfly API 키 설정
os.environ["SCRAPFLY_KEY"] = "my key"
SCRAPFLY_KEY = os.getenv("SCRAPFLY_KEY")
client = ScrapflyClient(key=SCRAPFLY_KEY)

# 결과를 저장할 리스트 초기화
lst = []

# 페이지를 순회하며 데이터 수집
for i in range(0, 240, 20):  # 페이지 번호 범위
    print(f"Scraping page {i // 20 + 1}...")

    url = f"https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Airbnb/reviews?start={i}"
    
    try:
        # Scrapfly를 사용하여 데이터 요청
        response = client.scrape({"url": url, "render_js": False})  # JavaScript 렌더링 필요 시 True로 설정
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
        main_data = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-tn-section": "reviews"})

        # 데이터 추출
        for data in main_data:
            try:
                title = data.find("h2").get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError:
                title = None
            
            try:
                author_status = data.find("span", attrs={"itemprop": "author"}).get_text(strip=True)
                author = author_status.split("-")[1] if "-" in author_status else None
                status = author_status.split("-")[0] if "-" in author_status else None
            except AttributeError:
                author, status = None, None
            
            try:
                review = data.find("span", attrs={"itemprop": "reviewBody"}).get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError:
                review = None
            
            try:
                pros = data.find("div", class_="cmp-review-pro-text").get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError:
                pros = None
            
            try:
                cons = data.find("div", class_="cmp-review-con-text").get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError:
                cons = None
            
            try:
                rating = data.find("div", attrs={"itemprop": "reviewRating"}).find("button")['aria-label'].split(" ")[0]
            except AttributeError:
                rating = None
            
            # 결과를 리스트에 추가
            lst.append([title, author, status, pros, cons, review, rating])
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error on page {i // 20 + 1}: {e}")

# DataFrame 생성
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Title', 'Author', 'Status', 'Pros', 'Cons', 'Review', 'Rating'])

# 결과 출력 및 저장
print(df.head())
df.to_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/indeed_reviews_scrapfly.csv", index=False)


Scraping page 1...
Error on page 1: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 2...
Error on page 2: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 3...
Error on page 3: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 4...
Error on page 4: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 5...
Error on page 5: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 6...
Error on page 6: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 7...
Error on page 7: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 8...
Error on page 8: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 9...
Error on page 9: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 10...
Error on page 10: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 11...
Error on page 11: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Scraping page 12...
Error on page 12: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method'
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Author, Status, Pros, Cons, Review, Rating]
Index: []


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm looking at your code and comparing that with https://scrapfly.io/docs/sdk/python#parameters.  You're calling scrape() with a dictionary parameter.  Is that intended?  What version of ScrapFly are you using?

Hello! Thank you for your kind and thoughtful question!
Q1. Why did I pass a dictionary to the scrape() method?
A1. According to the Scrapfly Python SDK documentation, the scrape() method is designed to accept a dictionary as a parameter to pass the URL and request options. Could you kindly point out if I may have made any mistakes or missed something in the way I implemented it?

Q2. Why is it important to check the Scrapfly version?
A2. I installed the Scrapfly SDK using the pip install . command after cloning the GitHub repository. I was trying to use the latest version of the SDK. However, there might be compatibility issues between the version from GitHub and the examples provided in the Scrapfly documentation. The reason I installed the SDK from GitHub is that I faced persistent installation issues on my Mac (using Colab). As a workaround, I resorted to cloning the repository. Would you happen to know a better or more reliable solution to handle this situation?

Thank you so much in advance for your help and guidance!
